# Recognise Registry and file changes

Tags: windows-registry

Tell me pls, is there any way or software that can recognise what files do this program read / use and what part of registry does it read / write? For Windows 8.1

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft System Internals tools has a few utilities to investigate registry changes, the most widely applauded of which is Process Monitor. The program is used in real time and can record changes to the Windows Registry, File, Network, Process/Service, and I think handles. Its pretty user friendly and intuitive. You can download System Internal Suite or the individual tools separately from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx

Comment: ProcMon is definitely the tool for the job. You can not only see what files and reg keys get opened, and with what permissions, but also how they are used. It's a free tool, supported by Microsoft, and pretty easy to use.